# $onChanges doesn't get called when pushing an item to an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Im using Angular 1.5.3 with typescript.

I have a `outer` and a `inner` component where the `outer`components holds an array named `arrayValue` which I pass to the `inner`component via `<`binding:

```
class InnerComponent {
  controller: Function = InnerController;    
  bindings: any = {
    arrayValue : "<"
  };
 ...
}
```

The `InnerController` uses the `$onChanges` method to track any changes from one-way bindings (e. g. `arrayValue`):

```
public $onChanges(changes: any){
      this.onChangesCalledCounter++;
      console.log(changes);
  }
```

If I now change the `arrayValue` within the `outer` component using:

```
public switchArrayValue(): void {
    if(this.arrayValue === this.fruits){
      this.arrayValue = this.vegetables;
    } else {
      this.arrayValue = this.fruits;
    }
  }
```

The  `$onChanges` within the `inner`component **gets** called. However, If I change the `switchArrayValue` method to perform a **push** instead of a reassignment of the array, the `$onChanges` method **won't** get called:

```
public switchArrayValue(): void {
    this.arrayValue.push("hello, world!");
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the `push` don't trigger the `$onChanges` and maybe show a workaround for that?

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/s1n3CXi1bV7jWiMBklAm?p=preview) (that I forked).

Comment: I'm not familiar with angular1, but if th echange detection works the same as in Angular2, then adding to an array doesn't actually trigger change detection because the array reference does not change. (See the answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38269812/angular-2-input-propery-changes-is-not-detect-by-angular-after-docheck/38269980#38269980). This could be completely invalid for angular1 though :-)

Comment: @DylanMeeus Thanks for that link, maybe its the same issue. Somehow I don't even get noticed using doCheck...

Comment: I am having this issue as well